# images.google.com effect for image gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-gallery, google-image-search

I'm trying to build a website with an image gallery that, when a thumbnail is clicked, a hidden div slides out and shows more information on the image and possibly a slideshow.

I've googled like crazy and the closest I can find is for menus. So I'm assuming I will have to use jquery to change the divs display tag from none to visible, but I'm just starting to understand jquery, and I am far from learning to code it from scratch.

Let me know if I am way off base or thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/)

Mark Up:

```
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
<li>
    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
        <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li><!-- ... --></li>
<!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Source: [THUMBNAIL GRID WITH EXPANDING PREVIEW](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have seen, and tried, but it doesn't work well with multiple slides inside of the preview